# Odd values_list and filter behavior in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to reduce the number of queries on the database in a Django app.  Rather than using three nested loops to execute quite a number of database queries, I'd like to use [the method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17128370/214892) that was described to me.

Given two classes, `Parentorg`

```
class Parentorgs(models.Model):
  parentorg = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column = 'parentorg_id', unique = True)
  parentorgname = models.CharField(max_length=100L, db_column='ParentOrg', unique = True) # Field name made lowercase.
  eff_date = models.DateField()
  exp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and `Contracts`

```
class Contracts(models.Model):
  parentorg = models.ForeignKey("Parentorgs")
  contractnum = models.CharField(max_length=10L, db_column='ContractNum', primary_key = True) 
  eff_date = models.DateField()
  exp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  contractname = models.CharField(max_length=100L, db_column='ContractName')
```

I want to get the results identical to a SQL inner join between the tables based on the primary-foreign key relationship.  Currently, I'm doing it as

```
for d in Parentorgs.objects.all():
  for e in Contracts.objects.filter(parentorg_id = e.parentorg) :
```

As you can see, this is pretty inefficient and places quite a load on the database.

As an alternative, I've tried

```
parentorg = Parentorgs.objects.values_list("pk", flat = True)
contracts = Contracts.objects.filter(parentorg_id = parentorg).values_list("pk", flat = True)
```

This gets the expected primary keys from Parentorgs, but `contracts` is an empty list.

If I replace `filter(parentorg_id = parentorg).values_list("pk", flat = True)` with `all`, I get 700+ results from `Contracts`, which is what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
parentorg = Parentorgs.objects.values_list("pk", flat=True)
contracts = Contracts.objects.filter(parentorg_id__in=parentorg)
```

You need to use `__in`.

Although to be honest, this is going to give you the same results as

```
Contracts.objects.all()
```

(Seeing as `parentorg` can't be null....)